# Move all numbers in a string to the end

Tags: python

I need help figuring out how to move numbers to the end of a string.

For example, `'y0b3'` should become `'yb03'`.

Comment: why did you tag passwords and generator? did you read the tag - descriptions? They have nothing to do whit what you ask. Where is the code you tried?

Comment: I removed the passwords-tag. FYI the question is receiving downvotes because you did not show any attempt.That's a shame because besides that I think it's a pretty useful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def group(string):

    digits = []
    non_digits = []
    for c in string:
        if c.isdigit():
            digits.append(c)
        else:
            non_digits.append(c)

    return ''.join(non_digits) + ''.join(digits)

result = group('y0b3')

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
yb03
```

The idea is to group each character into digit and `non_digits` then put the non digits first and the `digits` last. For joining both `digits` and `non_digits` use [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged generator... you could write the following generator for this task:

```
def digits_last(string):
    hold = []
    for c in string:
        if c.isdigit():
            hold.append(c)
        else:
            yield c
    yield from hold
```

Demo:

```
>>> ''.join(digits_last('y0b3y0b3u0b2'))
>>> 'ybybub030302'
```